# How do I prevent a PHP/Ajax script using serialize from multiple submits?

Tags: php, ajax

I am using PHP/Ajax/serialize to submit a simple form to itself. I use the following JavaScript to set it up to serialize/post the data. You can see the demo at https://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/addtocart.php. There is a link to a .txt version of the script.

```
$(function() {
  var form = $("#addtocart");
  $(form).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    $("#result").html( "" );
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(form).attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      success: function(html) { $("#result").html(html); }
    })
  });
});
```

Upon clicking the <kbd>Buy it now</kbd> button, it should only add a single line to the database. The first time you click on the button it adds a single line. If you click again, it adds two new lines, then three new lines, etc. It is sequentially adding more lines if you click submit. To stop this, you must reload the form.

Comment: FYI, `form` is already a jQuery object. You do not need to keep wrapping it in `$(form)`

Comment: You can disable buy button until ajax process finised

Comment: What does your HTML structure look like? Does your `#addtocart` form include the `#result` element? What is the HTML that is returned in the AJAX response?

Comment: You appear to be returning an entire HTML document in your AJAX response that includes scripts that add further _submit_ event handlers to your form. Don't do that, just respond with the HTML snippet you want to insert into your `#result` `<div>`

Comment: I reorganized the document as you suggested and it seems to work. Thx am good with this as the solution. I didn't try the answer offered by Rajkumar, but thx.

Answer (score -1):

Place the id of the button in `id = "addtocart_id"`

```
$(function() {
  var form = $("#addtocart");
  var count_btn = true;
  form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(count_btn){
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $("#result").html("");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function () {
          $("#addtocart_id").html("Please Wait...").prop("disabled", true);
        },
        success: function(html) { $("#result").html(html); }
        complete: function(){
                  count_btn = false;
                  $("#addtocart_id").html("Now Reload from browser");
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```